# Format cell in Excel if contents are a number or a function

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I understand conditional formatting but I don't see how it can help me. I'm looking at a sheet with many product entries and for most of them I get values from a table (`vlookup`) while for others I punch them in.

For example:

- Cell b2 contents are `=vlookup(a2,range,2,false)` and what is
  displayed is `0.6`
- Cell b3 I know `vlookup` will fail (there is no data for the product in the range for
  a3) so I manually put in  `0.8`.

With over a hundred lines like this how can I program a highlight/Format condition to visually distinguish between those that were introduced manually from those retrieved with `vlookup`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the aid of a UDF (user defined function) you *can* use Conditional Formatting:

```
Function IsFormula(r As Range) As Boolean
    IsFormula = r.HasFormula
End Function
```

And then use `IsFormula` in the format condition